# Send JSON blob as a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth0

Is it possible to send JSON to an endpoint which expects a file using Nodejs? This Auth0 endpoint expects a file containing JSON:

https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Jobs/post_users_imports

But really I don't want to have to save a file as I'll be making this call quite often. Ideally I'd like to be able to construct the JSON programmatically and then hit this endpoint with that JSON rather than a file - but still have the endpoint see that content as a file.

Is this possible?

Comment: Actually, consider this question: [Node.js can´t create Blobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14737423/691711) and then figure out what HTTP request library you want to use.